# Payfast payment gateway ITN rersponse in php

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment

I have integrated  payfast payment gateway. I did not get any response from payfast after redirecting success page and notify page. What are the response parameters and how to store transaction details in the database?

Comment: Does your notify_url return a 200 response?

Comment: @Daniel_ZA how can we check the status for notify_url?

Comment: @PathikVejani You can perform a post to the page using Postman or any other similar tool, and then view the response thereafter.

Answer (score 2):

PayFast will return their [return variables](https://www.payfast.co.za/documentation/return-variables/) to your system via the ITN callback after a successful payment has been made.

These return variables will **only** be returned to your `notify_url` if it returns a `header 200` response as per their [documentation](https://www.payfast.co.za/documentation/itn/).

> Receive the payment information from PayFast and then tell PayFast that this page is reachable by triggering a header 200, the payment engine will make a few attempts, one immediately and then one after 10 minutes again, then exponentially at longer intervals, until it receives an OK 200 from your web server.

You will be able to access the returned values via the `$_POST` variable and use these to update your database.

```
// Notify PayFast that information has been received
header( 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK' );
flush();

// Posted variables from ITN
$pfData = $_POST;

//update db
switch( $pfData['payment_status'] )
{
 case 'COMPLETE':
    // If complete, update your application, email the buyer and process the transaction as paid                    
 break;
 case 'FAILED':                    
    // There was an error, update your application
 break;
 default:
    // If unknown status, do nothing (safest course of action)
 break;
}
```

You can view the PayFast sample PHP ITN code [here](https://www.payfast.co.za/documentation/sample-code-php/).

Comment: Hi Daniel. A fellow SA'n here. I'm implementing Payfast in codeigniter framework and WAMP localhost environment on my laptop. Now it doesn't seem to resolve the PF source IP addresses, returning "Source IP not Valid" (using the PF code on their dev page. Do you think it's because it's on a "localhost" that I'm trying to achieve a return? (just to mention if relevant, my signature logic does match/validate, so I've gone beyond that point). Appreciate any input, thank you.

Comment: Hey Mario, PayFast will not be able to reach your local host machine when trying to post back the return variables to your notif_url. You can use a service such as Ngrok to set up a tunnel to your local host machine.

Comment: In the meantime I copied my script to my live server d-base.co.za and it came back with the same error. But, I did notice the script on PF's web page is slightly different to the version I got last year (the cURL portion). I'm just going to go through it and see if I spot something in the changes. I appreciate your reply. Will let you know, out of interest, if I find the issue. Thanks for responding buddy. Appreciated.

Comment: Now I'm confused and not sure if it's correct. when I dump `var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])` on screen, it comes back with my local router ip address, and the script is on my remote server. You can see it here [link](https://d-base.co.za/Payfastonline.php). I'm assuming this is correct? Also, I created a tunnel with your suggested Ngrok and the remote_address it returns is "::1". I'm not sure what to try.

Comment: I've never got this going. I tried Ngrok but always get `Bad source IP address`. PayFast support said to add their IP addresses to IP whitelist in Ngrok, but trying to find out where to manage that is a fruitless google search and Ngrok docs has no search. So I am still stuck using the return_url to trigger my database transactions. This really sucks.